# Force Neural Net to attempt to predict every class

Tags: neural-network, training

I am training a (deep) neural net to classify approximately 60 different classes. The range of occurrences of each class in the dataset is wide, 3 orders of magnitude from the most represented to the least represented. The neural net currently never predicts any of the 20 least represented classes.

Are there ways to mitigate this other than per class weighting, such as increased dropout or some other method? Can this be mitigated in the network structure? If per class weighting is the only option, is the best scheme to weight the class inversely to the frequency of occurrence?